# Prove or disprove, if $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]^n$ then $f|_{M}$ is integrable over M

Tags: calculus, integration, manifolds

> Given $f:[0,1]^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and $M^k\subseteq[0,1]^n$ manifold
> Prove or disprove, if $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]^n$ then $f|_{M}$ is integrable over $M$

I think the claim is true because if $f$ is integrable  on $[0,1]^n$ then on every subset it will be integrable but not sure whether that's true for manifolds as well

Comment: @Surb : this is not the right measure for $\int_M$. For $k<n$, you have $\int_{[0,1]^n} f\mathbf{1}_{M^k} = 0$. (If $M$ is regular enough)

Comment: @SolubleFish So we can say that the discontinuity points of $f$ are $M$ and therefore $f|_M$ is not integrable over $M$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the positive solution in one of the comments is wrong is that when we say "integrable over $M$" we're not talking about integrablity with respect to Lebesgue measure restricted to $M$, but rather integrability with respect to the appropriate lower-dimensional measure.

For example, say $n=2$, $$M=\{(x,x):0\le x\le \sqrt 2\}$$and $$f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)^{-2}.$$
Then $\int_{[0,1]^2}|f|<\infty$ (integrate in polar coordinates) but $$\int_M|f|=\int_0^{\sqrt 2}f(t,t)\,dt=\infty.$$

Comment: don't you get that $[0,1]^2\subset M$ in your example?

Comment: @convxy No, in fact $M$ is just the _diagonal_ of the unit square.